# Why am I not able to read a file with a different python version in Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm trying to install this tool on my windows computer going on 2 weeks now. After cloning the repository from GitHub, the instructions clearly says to go to my top-level source directory and type `scons` in order to build Alta on my machine. However, every time I use scons in my command line, I get the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jjohnson497-gtri/Documents/Greg/alta/SConstruct", line 38

    print '<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:'

          ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:')?
```

The first part of SConstruct code:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2014, 2015 CNRS
# Copyright (C) 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 Inria
# Copyright (C) 2015 Universite de Montreal
#
# This file is part of ALTA.
#
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0.  If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

import os
import sys
import SCons.SConf as C

# Arrange so that the 'obtain' module can always be imported.
top_srcdir = Dir('.').srcnode().abspath
sys.path += [ top_srcdir + '/external' ]

## Add ALTA custom cmd configurations
##
AddOption('--cfg', help='Specify a configuration file')


## Import configuration from a config file
##
configFile = GetOption('cfg')
if configFile == None:

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-windows-cl.py"
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-macos-clang.py"
    elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-linux-gcc.py"
    else:
        print '<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:'
        print '<<ERROR>>    scons --cfg=[filename]'
        print '<<ERROR>> Please find example of configuration files in ${ALTA}/configs/scons/'
        Exit(1)
#end
```

I figured this error must be because the python version the SConstruct file python is not compatible with python 3.x, so I created an anaconda environment with python 2.7.18 installed to address this problem, but I'm still getting no luck. For some reason, even when I try to use `Scons` in my new environment with python 2.7.18, I still get the following error. It like it's still reading the Sconstruct file with a newer version of python.
Below is the environment and what I'm typing to getting the following error...Am I doing this wrong?:

```
*(ALTA) C:\Users\jjohnson497-gtri\Documents\Greg\alta>scons*
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
  File "C:\Users\jjohnson497-gtri\Documents\Greg\alta\SConstruct", line 38

    print '<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:'

          ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:')?


**(ALTA) C:\Users\jjohnson497-gtri\Documents\Greg\alta>python -V
Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.**
```

This is the page I am referring to: http://alta.gforge.inria.fr/install.html . The instructions are clear as day, which is why this is so frustrating.

Comment: you are still using python 3.x, have you activated the environment before calling your python script

Comment: @rioV8 yes, the environment I want to use is called 'ATLA' , as shown in the parentheses. Also, if you look at the last block, I typed `python -V` which said `Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Comment: inside your `scons` script print `sys.version_info` to see it you use 2.x

Comment: Is `scons` an executable or just a file that you can edit? Try `where scons` to find the path to `scons`. If it is an editable file (as is the case in my Linux system), see if there is any hard coded reference to a specific pyhton version

Comment: @FlyingTeller this is what I get when I type `where scons`
`C:\Users\jjohnson497-gtri\Documents\Anaconda\Scripts\scons.exe`

Comment: @FlyingTeller Also, the only part in the Sconstruct file that has writing is in the beginning of the file, which can be found in the second block.

Comment: okay, you have installed scons using anaconda, so after creating and activating your python 2 env, simply install scons again `conda install -c conda-forge scons` which will install a scons that is built to use python 2